# Какой вопрос задавать к слову получится?

Tags: орфография

Какой вопрос задавать к слову "получится" в предложении "Получится ли?" для проверки "-тся/-ться"?

Comment: У вас, кстати, вопросы в заголовке и в теле вопроса не совпадают - это так задумано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно задавать тот вопрос, на который интересующий вас глагол отвечает (а иначе какой смысл его задавать?!). Если не очевидно, на какой вопрос отвечает слово, попробуйте представить, что вы его не расслышали в разговоре и хотите переспросить. А дальше в случае "-тся/-ться" все просто: если в проверочном вопросе глагол "делать" стоит в форме с мягким знаком, то и ваш глагол будет с мягким знаком, а если в вопросе мягкого знака нет - то и в вашем глаголе не будет. Примеры:

**1. Получится ли?**

-- Что сделае*т*?
-- Получи*т*ся.

**2. А может ли не получиться?**

-- Может что сдела*ть*?
-- Не получи*ть*ся.

**3. Мне нравится эта книга.**

-- Книга что делае*т*?
-- Нрави*т*ся.

**4. У него талант нравиться людям.**

-- Талант что дела*ть*?
-- Нрави*ть*ся.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить не совсем (или не для всех) очевидный момент.  Для иностранца, недостаточно хорошо владеющего русским языком, советовать задать проверочный вопрос иногда бесполезно. Он просто не сможет этого сделать в ряде случаев, так как чтобы найти правильный вопрос, нужно как минимум точно понять смысл предложения/фразы.   Замечательный пример я видел недавно в одной из российских передач (забыл название). Там речь шла о написании "ь" в конце существительных на шипящую - мышь, ложь, тушь, но - туш (мужск.), муж и т.п. ...

Comment: ... иностранец (венгр) написал "мыш", когда ему указали, что надо поставить на конце "ь", так как мышь женского рода, он возмутился: "Постойте, это против логики - мы **не можем знать какого рода существительное, если вы в задании нарочно убрали мягкий знак**, ведь его наличие или отсутствие это и есть единственный способ узнать род!" А вы говорите, проверочный вопрос :)

Comment: Придется составить протокол, тут какой вопрос задавать?

Comment: @jokelocker вопрос можно не задавать, т.к. слова "придёться" нет. Инфинитив - "прийтись".

Comment: @A.Toumantsev, если человек сам не понимает, что хочет сказать, то Вы правы, в этом случае заниматься проверкой орфографии несколько преждевременно... Я полагаю, что раз уж автор вопроса дошел до этого этапа, то смысл предложения он понимает.

Comment: @jokelocker, "придется" отвечает на вопрос "что сделает?", так же, как и "получится". А какой у Вас родной язык?

Answer (score 2):

"Что сделает? — Получится". Это будущее время.

Comment: А почему важно какое время?

Comment: Я просто поясняю, в какой форме этот глагол стоит, на всякий случай. Вообще же рекомендую не проверочные вопросы задавать, а сходить на http://tsya.ru/

Comment: а если знаешь в какой форме глагол легче подобрать правильный вопрос?

Comment: «Придется составить протокол» а тут какой вопрос задавать? @MigMit

Comment: Никакой. Надо *знать*, что "придётся" не инфинитив, потому что такого инфинитива не существует, есть только "приходиться" (с совершенно другим смыслом). А раз не инфинитив - мягкого знака нет.

Comment: @A.Toumantsev есть ещё несколько случаев, кроме инфинитива, когда ставится мягкий знак. Ещё раз рекомендую http://tsya.ru/

Comment: @MigMit Я знаю, но ни один из других случаев тоже не подходит. Я там был. Давайте уж сюда процитируем для ленивых.   **Ь ставится**:
1\В инфинитиве: "умывать(ся)", "беречь(ся)".
2\В окончании 2-го лица единственного числа настоящего/будущего времени: "умываешь(ся)", "бережёшь(ся)".
3\После согласных (кроме "й" и "г" – ляг(те)) в формах повелительного наклонения: "исправь(те)".
4\В возвратной частице (суффиксе), стоящей после гласного звука: "вернусь", "вернитесь", "вернулись", "вернувшись".
В остальных случаях в глагольных окончаниях ь не ставится: "он пошёл умываться", но: "он умывается"

Comment: @MigMit а почему бы не задать проверочные вопросы? Я, например, их уже лет тридцать пять задаю, с тех пор, когда tsya.ru еще и в помине не было ... Вообще, не так давно еще были времена, когда людям приходилось писать не только на компьютере, знаете ли ...

Comment: @A.Toumantsev, а "прийтись"?

Comment: В смысле? Пункт 4. Или поясните вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where the accent is. "ПолУчится ли" - что сделает? "ПолучИться ли" - что сделать?

Comment: Are you sure it's important, may you extend your answer and add some reference to information backing this importance.

Comment: @MolbOrg I am not sure what you mean by "important". There are certainly more important things in life. So, no, I am not sure this (or the original question for that matter) is "important" (it would depend on your priorities). I _am_ sure that it is correct though. I also think, that it is complete, i.e., I don't see any information that could be usefully added here. If you see it, please do not hesitate to make a suggestion.

Comment: Я сам не уверен, что именно я имел в виду. У меня была мысль ударение в данном случае важн*о*, но имеет ли это отношение к написанию мягкого знака в слове, и результат(да и результат ли, а не следствие) каких правил или исключений. Поэтом мне кажется уместным добавить в этот ответ, ссылками или как, обоснование в виде формальных правил, ну или чтото из официальной орфографической науки, без необходимости, для читающего этот ответ, гуглить или рыться гдето еще. В этом смысле ответ кажется мне не полным и может быть улучшен. Само по себе ваше замечание  интересно, но выглядит как наблюдение.

Comment: @MolbOrg Ударение имеет отношение к написанию мягкого знака постольку поскольку оно изменяет значение и форму слова. Дело не в том, что есть какое-то правило ставить или не ставить мягкий знак в зависимости  от ударения (его нет), а в том, что если просто посмотреть на слово "получит?ся", то невозможно сказать нужен там мягкий знак или не нужен, не зная, на какой слог приходится ударение. 
Или наоборот, невозможно сказать какой слог ударный, не зная, есть ли мягкий знак.

Comment: Именно эта мысль и была у меня камнем предкновения, при мысли о возможных ответах ОПу. И мне кажется эта информация абсолютно достойна  своего места в ответе. Вот ее бы и добавить.